# How to find the PrivateKey for decrypt smime.p7m message with RecipientInformation?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, bouncycastle, private-key, smime

I try to use the follow Java code to decrypt a S/MIME message from the JavaMail API:

```
        String mimeType = mail.getContentType();
        if( mimeType == null ) {
            return mail;
        }
        ContentType contentType = new ContentType( mimeType );
        if( "application/pkcs7-mime".equals( contentType.getBaseType() ) //
            && "smime.p7m".equals( contentType.getParameter( "name" ) ) ) {
            Object content = mail.getContent();
            if( content instanceof InputStream ) {
                CMSEnvelopedDataParser ep = new CMSEnvelopedDataParser( (InputStream)content );
                RecipientInformationStore recipients = ep.getRecipientInfos();
                Iterator<RecipientInformation> it = recipients.getRecipients().iterator();
                RecipientInformation recipient = (RecipientInformation) it.next();
                recipient.getContent(new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(privateKey).setProvider( provider) );
            }
        }
```

I have a list of PrivateKeys. How can I find the right PrivateKey to pass in the JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient constructor? I think that this should be possible with the RecipientInformation object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S/MIME messages are usually encrypted using publickey from a *certificate* specifically an X.509 or PKIX certificate (PKIX is the Internet 'version' or technically profile of X.509) and KeyTransRI -- if that is indeed what you have, your code doesn't check -- or KeyAgreeRI contains a 'recipient id' which actually identifies the certificate; you are expected to map that certificate to the corresponding privatekey, which is how Java crypto normally works (the `KeyStore` API stores a privatekey with its corresponding certificate or chain).

`RecipientInformation.getRID()` returns a `RecipientId`, normally `KeyTransRecipientId` or `KeyAgreeRecipientId` corresponding to the `RecipientInfo`, either of which allows you to get the issuer and serial of the cert, or the 'subject key identifier' an extension in most certs that normally [contains a hash of its subject key bit-string value](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280.html#section-4.2.1.2).

Similarly signing is done with the privatekey, and `SignerInfo` includes the id of the corresponding certificate, which is distributed to and used by reliers to verify the signature.

Comment: Must I check both 'serial number' and 'subject key identifier' to match a certificate or is every value unique enough?

Comment: serial is only guaranteed unique within one CA, so you are _supposed_ to use issuer and serial together, or instead SKI which is a hash and normallly unique although rfc8551 warns it might not be. In practice nowadays, due to CABforum rules after 'hashclash' and 'shattered', many (most?) CAs put enough entropy in serial you can probably get away with using it alone, although I prefer to follow and state the [official rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-6.2.1)